# Axis2 embedded in my web app is not working

Tags: apache-axis

OKay I lost alsmost the whole day on this. 
I have a webapp where I would like to add AXIS2 and start working. 
I added AxisServlets in the web.xml file like -

```
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>Apache-Axis Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

I also added Services.xml file like

```
<service name="ReportViewerService">
    <description>
        This is a sample Web Service for illustrating Attachments API of Axis2
    </description>
    <parameter name="ServiceClass">myclass</parameter>
    <operation name="getReport">
        <actionMapping>urn:getReport</actionMapping>
        <messageReceiver class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
    </operation>
</service>
```

The directory structure is as mentioned [here](http://wso2.org/library/90)

```
WEB-ING
  | - conf
  |     |- axis2.xml
  |-lib
  |  |- all libs
  |-services
       |-ReportViewerService
               | - META-INF
                     |-services.xml
  |- web.xml
```

The problem is - after all of these, the service endpoint will not come, I can not see the WSDL file http://localhost:8080/BOReportingServer/services/ReportViewerService?wsdl -- this gives an exception like -

```
Throwable occurred: javax.servlet.ServletException: File &quot;/axis2-web/listSingleService.jsp&quot; not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I am able to embed AXIS2 in my webapp.

It is as simple as mentioned in the [tutorial](http://wso2.org/library/90) , only thing is:

- I never got the jars properly placed under *WEB-INF/lib* directory. 
  Once I started from the very beginning and removed all the unwanted jars and duplicate jars from the WEB-INF/lib directory, so started working.

Comment: Check out, that'**s disabled** your **rebel**-develoment-configuration into tomcat7-bootstrap as like your _catalina.bat_ or _catalina.sh_.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same symptom when trying to deploy an axis2 service with a packed (unexploded) .war file on a tomcat server.

```
"Throwable occurred: javax.servlet.ServletException: File &quot;/axis2-web/listSingleService.jsp&quot; not found"
```

The solution was to add the 'services.list' file to the /WEB-INF/services/ folder. 
(There is also a modules.list file for the /WEB-INF/modules/ folder.)

These are just a text files listing out the service archive files in the folder.

```
/WEB-INF
 |-modules
   |-addressing-1.6.1.mar
   |-...
   |-modules.list
   |-...
   |-soapmonitor-1.6.1.mar
 |-services
   |-ReportViewerService.aar
   |-services.list
```

In the .list files, contain just the names of the archive files, one entry per line.

Reference: http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/app_server.html

Answer (score -2):

You also deployed axis2.war in your servlet container, right?

In order for Axis2 to work properly, you need to deploy it to a servlet container.  A tutorial can be found [here](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_5_1/installationguide.html#servlet_container).  You'll know you've done it properly when the Axis2 "Happy" page can be shown.

Once you've done that, you should be able to bundle up your service (in the structure you've described above in your question) into an .aar file and deploy it using the axis2 servlet.

Comment: No, why do I need to deploy axis2.war file? I am trying to embed it in my webapp.

Comment: Axis2 _IS_ a web app...that's how it provides services.  Trust me, this step is required.  :)

Comment: Can you please tell me the exact steps then? Like where from where I should download it and in this case where would my services stay?

Comment: Doesn't make sense to deploy axis2.war if you want to embed it.