# Deploy Axis2 .aar without Axis2 web application

Tags: java, apache-axis

I would like to know if there's a way to deploy an Axis2 .aar file without having to include it as part of the Axis 2 web application.
I know that my question is short, but there isn't much information that I could provide to direct my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.

The axis2 web archive (axis2.war) can be extracted once and never has to be extracted again after that.

Following changes within the axis2 webapp directory are common:

- You add modules in 'axis2/WEB-INF/modules/'.
- You add libraries in 'axis2/WEB-INF/lib/'.
- You change the configuration in 'axis2/WEB-INF/conf/axis2.xml' file.
- You deploy your services in 'axis2/WEB-INF/services/'.

Also, there's an option for hot deploys in the services directory. In the axis2.xml file, the folowing line enables this:

```
<parameter name="hotdeployment">true</parameter>
```

You can also override the default location of services with the following configuration parameter:

```
<parameter name="ServicesDirectory">service</parameter>
```

You can, of course, also make symlinks (unix/linux) instead, but I would not recommend polluting your installation with those.

So, to wrap it up, after your initial deploy of the axis2.war file, you do not need to redeploy it, it can stay, and you can deploy your .aar-files in the services directory. If hot deploy is not enabled (default), you need to restart your tomcat server/reload context manually.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to deploy an axis2 web service in an existing application, if so, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2428837/186896)